# Ruby method conditions

Tags: ruby, methods

The instructions for my program are to make a method that takes a string and returns dashes around any odd numbers, but with the exception that the end result may not begin or end with a dash `"-"`. For example, if I enter `"95601137"`, it should return

```
"9 - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 7"
```

Here's the code:

```
def dashes(number)
  string = number.to_s
  i=0
  final = []
  while i<string.length
    digit = string[i].to_i
    if ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i==0) && (string.length == 1) && ((string.length - 1) == 0)
      final.push(string[i])
    elsif ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i==0) && (string.length != 1) && ((string.length - 1) > 0)
      final.push(string[i] + "-")
    elsif ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i>0) && (i!=(string.length - 1)) && ((string.length != 1))
      final.push("-" + string[i] + "-")
    elsif ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i!=0) && (i==(string.length - 1))
      final.push("-" + string[i])
    else final.push(string[i])
    end
    i+=1
  end
  return final
end

puts("Give me any number.")
answer = gets
puts dashes(answer)
```

My program has two issues:

1. When I enter `9`, it returns `"9-"`. How come?
2. When I enter a string that ends with an odd number, it puts a dash at the end, which it's not expected. I thought I made my `if` conditions strict, too.

Comment: I'm very grateful for all your guys' help!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose another solution:

```
def dashes(num)
  str = num.to_s
  dashed_arr = str.chars.map.with_index do |digit, index|
    next digit if digit.to_i.even?
    if index.zero? # is it first digit?
      "#{digit} -"
    elsif index == str.length - 1 # is it last digit?
      "- #{digit}"
    else 
      "- #{digit} -"
    end
  end

  dashed_arr.join(' ').gsub('- -', '-')
end

puts dashes(95601137)
puts dashes(909)
# => "9 - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 7"
# => "9 - 0 - 9"
```

Let's review it step by step:

1. `str = num.to_s` - convert our number to a string representation, i.e. `"95601137"`
2. `str.chars` - split our string by chars. We get an array of chars, like this: `["9", "5", "6", "0", "1", "1", "3", "7"]`, because we want to iterate them, one by one.
3. `map` takes one array and converts it to another array by the code supplied in `do ... end`.

For example, let's take this code:

```
[1, 2, 3].map do |num| 
  num * 2 
end
# => [2, 4, 6]
```

If you need also an index of your element, you can similarly use `.map.with_index` (index starts from zero):

```
[1, 2, 3].map.with_index do |num, index| 
  num * index # index takes values 0, 1, 2
end 
# => [0, 2, 6]
```

So, in the block in code above, we have each digit from our number as `digit` and its 0-based position as `index`.

4. `next digit if digit.to_i.even?`. We don't need even digits, so we can skip them. `.to_i` is needed to convert `digit` to integer, so we can query is it even or odd. `next digit` just returns current digit and moves execution to next digit.
5. Now we're left only with odd digits, so we just need to put dashes correctly, depending on the digit position: if it's a first digit, append a dash, if it's a last digit then put the dash in front of the digit, otherwise just surround digit with dashes:

   ```
   if index.zero? # first digit, index is zero-based
     "#{digit} -"
   elsif index == str.length - 1 # last digit
     "- #{digit}"
   else 
     "- #{digit} -"
   end
   ```
6. We save intermediate result in `dashed_arr` variable to make code readable. Right now it contains the following: `["9 -", "- 5 -", "6", "0", "- 1 -", "- 1 -", "- 3 -", "- 7"]`. As you can see, we're almost done, we just need to connect all the elements of array back to string.
7. `dashed_arr.join(' ')`. Join back elements of array into a string with single space as a separator. We get this string: `9 - - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - - 1 - - 3 - - 7`. Hmm, it seems we need to delete some consecutive dashes.
8. Let's do it with `gsub`: `dashed_arr.join(' ').gsub('- -', '-')`. `gsub` just searches all occurrences of first string and replaces them with the second string, which is exactly what we need: `9 - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 7`.

We're done! I hope it was also fun for you as for me.

Comment: If you enter "909" the output is "909". I'm not sure, but from what I understood from the problem, the output must be "9 - 0 - 9"

Comment: @Wagner It seems you're right, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One more implementation, inspired by [Cary Swoveland's first implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831504/273444):

```
str = '95601137'

separators = str.each_char.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).map do |pair| 
  pair.any?(&:odd?) ? ' - ' : ' '
end

str.chars.zip(separators).join
# => "9 - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 7"
```

Comment: Very good! A tiny suggestion: when you break a string into characters to feed an `Enumerable` method, such as `map`, use `each_char`, which returns an `Enumerator`, rather than `chars`, which returns a (temporary) array. `zip` is  `Array` method, so there you must use `chars`.

Comment: Alternatively, `(str.each_char.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).map do |p,q| "#{p}#{ [p,q].any?(&:odd?) ? ' - ' : ' ' }"; end << str[-1]).join #=> "9 - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 7"`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
answer = gets
```

with:

```
answer = gets.strip
```

Then, you will get the correct output for input: `9`

Because, when you give `9` as input and hit `enter`, your input is actually: `"9\n"` which has length 2. That's why it was printing `9-`.
Using: `gets.strip` you just [strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) out the `\n`.

To remove the last `-` (if any), you can use [chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
final_result = final.join('').chomp('-')
```

And, to remove the first `-` (if any), you can use this logic:

```
   if final_result[0] == '-'
    final_result[1..-1]
   else
    final_result
   end
```

Here is the full working version of the code (**keeping as much as of your code**):

```
def dashes(number)
    string = number.to_s

    i = 0

    final = []

    while i < string.length

        digit = string[i].to_i

        if ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i==0) && (string.length == 1) && ((string.length - 1) == 0)             
            final.push(string[i])
        elsif ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i==0) && (string.length != 1) && ((string.length - 1) > 0)               
            final.push(string[i] + "-")
        elsif ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i>0) && (i!=(string.length - 1)) && ((string.length != 1))               
            final.push("-" + string[i] + "-")
        elsif ((digit)%2 != 0) && (i!=0) && (i==(string.length - 1))                
            final.push("-" + string[i])
        else 
            final.push(string[i])
        end

    i += 1

    end

   final_result = final.join('').gsub('--', '-').chomp('-')
   puts "final_result: #{final_result.inspect}"

   if final_result[0] == '-'
    final_result[1..-1]
   else
    final_result
   end
end

puts("Give me any number.")

answer = gets.strip

puts dashes(answer)

# > Give me any number.
# > 95601137
# > "9-5-60-1-1-3-7"
```

Comment: You are welcome and welcome to stackoverflow. You can always accept the best answer for your question and also you can upvote the other answers that you like and find helpful. To see how accepting answer works, please see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways, for:

```
str = "95601137"
```

**Use an enumerator**

With this method you would use [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) to create an enumerator to which you would send the methods [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek):

```
enum = str.each_char

s = ''
loop do
  c = enum.next
  s << c
  n = enum.peek
  s << ((c.to_i.odd? || n.to_i.odd?) ? ' - ' : ' ')
end
s #=> "9 - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 7"
```

The key here is that when the enumerator is at the last element (`'7'`) `peek` raises a `StopIteration` exception. The exception is handled by [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking out of the loop.

Use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)

We can use `gsub` three times, each with a regular expression, to:

- put the dashes in the correct locations
- space as desired around the dashes
- space as desired between even digits

```
r = /       
    (\A\d) # match beginning of string followed by a digit, save in group 1
    |      # or
    (\d\z) # match a digit followed by end of string, save in group 2
    |      # or
    (\d)   # match a digit, save in capture group 3
    /x     # extended mode

str = "95601137"

str.gsub(r) do |s|
  if $1
    $1.to_i.odd? ? "#{$1}-"  : $1
  elsif $2
    $2.to_i.odd? ? "-#{$2}"  : $2 
  elsif $3
    $3.to_i.odd? ? "-#{$3}-" : $3
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "'#{s}' is not a digit" 
  end
end.gsub(/-+/, ' - ').gsub(/(\d)(\d)/,'\1 \2')
  #=> "9 - 5 - 6 0 - 1 - 1 - 3 - 7"
```

Comment: Thanks, Cary, it's very interesting! Your enumerator implementation inspired me with the idea that `each_cons(2)` + `zip` can work too. Thanks!

Comment: Alexey, that would be a rather elegant solution. I suggest you post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation, there's probably some smarter ways to do it:

```
def dashes(number)
  number                              # => 95601137
    .to_s                             # => "95601137"
    .chars                            # => ["9", "5", "6", "0", "1", "1", "3", "7"]
    .map(&:to_i)                      # => [9, 5, 6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7]
    .map {|i| i.odd? ? "-#{i}-" : i } # => ["-9-", "-5-", 6, 0, "-1-", "-1-", "-3-", "-7-"]
    .join                             # => "-9--5-60-1--1--3--7-"
    .gsub(/^-|-$/, '')                # => "9--5-60-1--1--3--7"
    .gsub('--', '-')                  # => "9-5-60-1-1-3-7"
end
```